# Am I able to calculate autograd of NN outputs wrt network inputs in flux.jl?

Tags: neural-network, julia, autograd, flux.jl

I have a NN that is a function f:(t, v) -> (x,z). Am I able to calculate an autograd partial derivative df/dt? I want to use the the autograd calculation in a regularization term in my loss function.

```
yhat = net((t,v))
#calculate current value of df/dt here
penalized_loss(yhat, y) = loss(yhat, y) + penalty(df/dt)
```

I want to do something like

```
df/dt = gradient(net,t)
```

but I don't know how to tell the gradient function what the input (t) is

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/training/#Custom-Training-loops-1), you can use the `gradient` this way:

```
function my_custom_train!(loss, ps, data, opt)
  ps = Params(ps)
  for d in data
    gs = gradient(ps) do
      loss(d...)
    end
    update!(opt, ps, gs)
  end
end
```

This `gradient(ps) do ... end` is the Julian idiom to:

```
gradient(loss(d...), ps);
```

`gradient` comes from [Zygote.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/Zygote.jl), you can read more about [here](https://fluxml.ai/Zygote.jl/latest/).

Comment: I'm not looking for the gradient of my loss function wrt parameters, im looking for the gradient of the NN output wrt NN inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a feed-forward neural network you can use [BetaML](https://github.com/sylvaticus/BetaML.jl) and in particular copy the [getGradient](https://github.com/sylvaticus/BetaML.jl/blob/6a02de0223931a9cc3053c13fc42c7b62352603e/src/Nn/Nn.jl#L406) function ("step 1" and "step 2") to retrieve the backward stack up to the inputs.